# prime31 gamecenter plugin tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, prime31

i've bought the game center plugin yesterday and i'm new to unity and i'm very confused.. i'm good in objective-c and i've done game center alot.. but with this plugin there's now (how to) there's no neat document of how do i implement it .. i built the app to xcode with the test scene they've provided on unity 3.5 and it gives me error message

> > EntryPointNotFoundException: _gameCenterRetrieveFriends
>
> ```
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) GameCenterBinding:_gameCenterRetrieveFriends (bool)
>
>   at GameCenterBinding.retrieveFriends (Boolean loadProfileImages) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>   at GameCenterGUIManager.OnGUI () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>
>
> (Filename:  Line: -1)
> ```

and it can't check if the gamecenter is available or not and it can't authenticate .. i spent alot of time try to figure out what the problem .. i've put in unity the app identifier and everything is as what i did on the normal iphone apps .. but always error with nothing happens.. what the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short doc at their web site for [GameCenter Plugin](http://prime31.com/unity/docs/#gameCenterDoc) and some pieces in the Unity3D manual:

[Plugins (Pro/Mobile-Only Feature)](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html)

[Building Plugins for iOS](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

I recommend the [Unity3D Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/10-Unity-Support) because Prime31 is very active there.

Answer (score 0):

did you run the xcode project on the iPhone simulator?
prime31 plugins are using native bindings to iOS, which do not work on the iPhone simulator.
try running it on a real iOS device.